# node:events:505, errno: -4094, code: 'UNKNOWN', syscall: 'lstat' How to solve

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run `npx react-native start` (as all the other days, it works normally) and today it gives me this error:

**The ERROR**

```
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at Walker._checkedEmitError (D:\Study\dut-pbl-ui-local\dut-pbl-ui\ClinicAppointmentUI\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\watchers\NodeWatcher.js:134:12)           at Walker.emit (node:events:527:28)    at D:\Study\dut-pbl-ui-local\dut-pbl-ui\ClinicAppointmentUI\node_modules\walker\lib\walker.js:52:12
    at callback (D:\Study\dut-pbl-ui-local\dut-pbl-ui\ClinicAppointmentUI\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:306:20)    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'D:\\Study\\dut-pbl-ui-local\\dut-pbl-ui\\ClinicAppointmentUI\\node_modules\\.react-native-reanimated-pAXdN46R\\android\\.cxx\\Debug\\371829e3\\arm64-v8a\\CMakeFiles\\reanimated.dir\\bfd4a65ab8cb7ed9bf61739c95179c3b\\cpp\\ReanimatedRuntime\\ReanimatedHermesRuntime.cpp.o'
}
```

**I'VE TRIED :**

- Deleted node_modules packages and package-lock.json and run npm install. It still fails after many trials
- I have tried react-native start --reset-cache and it gives the same error
- I have tried npm cache verify  then npm cache clear --force and it gives the same error

Is there any solution without recreate a new project?

Please help me